# xorg server crashes because of custom kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, xorg, kernel-modules

I did compile custom linux kernel, without using modules, but when I try to start x server, screen freezes, it even does not allow switch to other tty.
The major difference in logs of X server is the line:

```
[...] xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Function not implemented)
```

It seems, that I disabled some major feature in kernel config, but I have no idea which one it is.

**Question is: which config option causes this behaviour?**

Or how can it be determined? maybe, an abstract *'not implemented'* can be traced some way?

- Linux version : 6.4.0.
- Graphics driver: intel i915.
- Required firmware included

Comment: I would guess you've removed serial ports from the kernel. Please read a tutorial. This one is a good one: https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-compile-linux-kernel-0/ PS create your first kernel out of the config of a working kernel